# Extract list element in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my first python program. I use the below code to generate combinations for a given range.

```
for k in range(0, items+1):        
    for r in range(0, items+1):        
        if (r-k) > 0:
            res = [x for x in itertools.combinations(range(k, r), r-k)]            
            print res
```

Let say items=4, the code produce 10 combinations

```
            #     
            # [(0,)]
            # [(0, 1)]
            # [(0, 1, 2)]
            # [(0, 1, 2, 3)]
            # [(1,)]
            # [(1, 2)]
            # [(1, 2, 3)]
            # [(2,)]
            # [(2, 3)]
            # [(3,)]
            #
```

My questions are

- (a) How can I retrieve each element in each combinations, let say, in  [(1, 2, 3)], how can I retrieve value at offset 0  (i.e. 1) ?
- (b) How can I store return value from itertools.combinations into a list array in "res" (eg, res[0] = [(0,)]  , res[1] = [(0, 1)] ?
- (c) Let say I want to use map(), How can I make the value eg [(0, 1)]  as key, and assign a random value to this key?

Comment: That list comprehension isn't really doing anything for you. Why not simply `print itertools.combinations(range(k, r), r - k)`?

Comment: @isbadawi Because `itertools.combinations` returns a generator

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations(range(k, r), r - k))`, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- a) Use indexes:

  ```
  >>> [(1, 2, 3)][0][0]
  1
  ```
- b) I don't 100% understand this question, but instead of using a list comprehension as you have done, you can use `list(itertools.combinations(...))`
- c) I think you are misunderstanding what `map()` does. `map(str, [1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to:

  ```
  [str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
  ```

If you want to give `[(0, 1)]` a value, you can use a dictionary, but you have to use `(0, 1)`  instead of `[(0, 1)]` because you would otherwise get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. If you want a "random value", I guess you can use the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module:

```
import random
{(0, 1) : random.randint(1,10)} # This is just an example, of course
```

---

To store all the outputs in one list, you can use a massive list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(itertools.combinations(range(x, i), i-x)) for x in range(0, items+1) for i in range(0, items+1) if (i-x) > 0]
[[(0,)], [(0, 1)], [(0, 1, 2)], [(0, 1, 2, 3)], [(1,)], [(1, 2)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(2,)], [(2, 3)], [(3,)]]
```

Comment: For (b), I want to store all generated combinations into an array, now, "res" is not an array. I tried  res[i] = list(itertools.combinations(range(k, r), r-k)) , where i=0, res = [], but it gives "IndexError: list assignment index out of range".

Comment: arh...Sorry, I am coding python with a C mind. I used res.append(list(itertools.combinations(range(k, r), r-k)))  . It works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I initially posted this as a comment, but I think it's really an answer.

You're misapplying `itertools.combinations`, and it's getting in the way of your ability to get your data in a convenient way. `itertools.combination(range(k, r), r-k)` is always going to yield exactly one value, `range(k,r)`. That's unnecessary; you should just use the range directly.

However, the `for` and `if` statements you use to produce your `k` and `r` values *are* a combination. Instead of the three levels of statements in your original code, you can use `for k, r in itertools.combinations(range(items+1), 2)`. I suspect you were trying to do this when you put the `itertools.combinations` call in your code, but it ended up in the wrong place.

So, to finally get around to your actual question: To access your data, you need to put all your items into a single data structure, rather than printing them. A list comprehension is an easy way to do that, especially once you've simplified the logic producing them, as my suggested changes above do:

```
import itertools

items = 4

results = [range(k, r) for k,r in itertools.combinations(range(items+1),2)]
print results
# prints [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

If you need to access the individual items, you use indexing into the `results` list, then into its member lists, as necessary.

```
print results[6]    # prints [1, 2, 3]
print results[6][0] # prints 1
```